# почему не работает -webkit-text-stroke когда заходишь на сайт с телефона (не появляется белая обводка вокруг букв)? А когда с компьютера появляется

Tags: css3, html5

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: при входе на сайт с компьютера]

```css
h1 {
    font-size: 5vw
    color: white
    padding-top: 2vw
    padding-bottom: 2vw
    font-family: 'Rubik Mono One', sans-serif
    font-weight: 700
    text-shadow: 10px 10px 30px #5473B6,  -10px -10px 30px #F8E31A
    -webkit-text-stroke: 0.1px //#F8E31A
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent
    letter-spacing: 10px
    text-align: center }
```

```html
<h1>school BJJ Lutador</h1>
```

### Заголовок

```
h1 {font-size: 5vw
    color: white
    padding-top: 2vw
    padding-bottom: 2vw
    font-family: 'Rubik Mono One', sans-serif
    font-weight: 700
    text-shadow: 10px 10px 30px #5473B6,  -10px -10px 30px #F8E31A
    -webkit-text-stroke: 0.1px //#F8E31A
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent
    letter-spacing: 10px
    text-align: center }
```

[image: при входе на сайт с телефона]

Comment: в обоих случаях один и тоже браузер. Заранее спасибо!!!

Comment: для наглядности попробуйте сами зайти сначала с компьютера а потом телефона на focik.online

Comment: тот код который есть тут в сниппете и не должен работать. причем не только обводка но и вообще весь, разве что кроме первого свойства(но это не точно) ибо нет символа ";" нигде... в нативном CSS его можно опускать только в одном случае - если завершаемое свойство последнее и после него есть символ "}" да и двойному слэшу в CSS тоже не место...